# How to get block height, if I have only block header?

Tags: c++, height

Imagine I executed [ReadBlockFromDisk](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3c40bc6726b6dc639c4ca2c00c720bccd4cd4dc7/src/validation.cpp#L1135) and now I have valid instance of CBlock.

How do I read height of this block?

```
CBlock block = ...;
CBlockIndex index(block);
assert (index.nHeight != 0); // fails, nHeight is default initialized
```

Comment: I think for have the height of block you can analysis of the bitcoin blockchain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this function from `validation.h` does the job:

```
CBlockIndex* LookupBlockIndex(const uint256& hash)
```

Comment: The answer I posted is the answer to your next question. "How do I load the index so this function can work?"

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to get a full node started up by calling `AppInitMain` in `init.cpp` in order to get the index subsystem running.

Otherwise it can't query the index database to get the block height.

The node subsystem must be warmed up and running in order to run queries linked from C++ directly. You'd also need to synchronize the calls and respect locks - not easy.

Running AppInitMain is basically the same as running `bitcoind`, so you're probably better off calling into the RPC interface from C++ and passing the `getblock <hash> 1` command to it. The process the resulting JSON.

`getblock <hash> 1` returns something like this

```
{
  "hash": "00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048",
  "confirmations": 600340,
  "strippedsize": 215,
  "size": 215,
  "weight": 860,
  "height": 1,
  "version": 1,
  "versionHex": "00000001",
  "merkleroot": "0e3e2357e806b6cdb1f70b54c3a3a17b6714ee1f0e68bebb44a74b1efd512098",
  "tx": [
    "0e3e2357e806b6cdb1f70b54c3a3a17b6714ee1f0e68bebb44a74b1efd512098"
  ],
  "time": 1231469665,
  "mediantime": 1231469665,
  "nonce": 2573394689,
  "bits": "1d00ffff",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200020002",
  "nTx": 1,
  "previousblockhash": "000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f",
  "nextblockhash": "000000006a625f06636b8bb6ac7b960a8d03705d1ace08b1a19da3fdcc99ddbd"
}
```

Which includes the height and other data.

Comment: I wanted to get a name of C++ function to retrieve it, but anyway, thanks.